# Angular Directive vs. Controller function

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I have a list of itineraries displayed on a page. Each itinerary has a select button. This select button is a directive.

```
.directive('itinerarySelectBtn', ['itineraryFactory', 
    function(itineraryFactory){
        return {
            restrict: 'E', // defining the container as an element
            scope: {
                itinerary: '=', // html element we are injecting this directive too
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/content/partials/directives/results/results-list.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.on('click' , function(){
                    itineraryFactory.itinerary = scope.itinerary;
                });
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This button does nothing else, other than receive the itinerary object via scope: '=' and then assigns it in my itineraryFactory to the itinerary object. I do this so I can utilise my getter and setter in my itineraryFactory and pull it into my controller.
In my controller:

```
$scope.itineraries = itineraryFactory.getItinerary();
```

My question is: Is this overkill, should this be a directive? Alternatively I could just have a $scope.function in my controller and do the same thing. The button could just be part of the ng-repeat that lists the itineraries on the page.

I feel like having a setItinerary() function in my controller would essentially be the same and could be executed via ng-click on the button.

Thoughts?

Regards,

Comment: I can't see you needing anything beyond `<button ng-click="controllerScopeItinerary = repeaterItinerary">Click me!</button>`

Comment: Actually that is even better. You are tight. I have over-complicated things. Feel free to post that as an answer if you'd like. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything in your template.

Say you want to assign `$scope.chosenItinerary` in your controller from the list in `$scope.itineraries`

```
<div ng-repeat="itinerary in itineraries">
    <button ng-click="chosenItinerary = itinerary">Pick this one!</button>
</div>
```